# POST a DateTime? argument in ISO format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding, datetime-format

My team has decided to try to use ISO date format YYYY-MM-DD wherever possible in the applications we write. We aren't adopting a culture, it has nothing to do with our location or language, we just prefer to deal with dates in this form.

Whenever I post the form, my "Edit" method correctly receives the updated "Text" argument, but does not get the updated "DueDate" value (the value the model started with). I can verify that the updated value is being sent in the POST traffic.

I think I've tracked this down to a DateTime format issue, but I can't seem to find a clear answer on how to deal with it.

How do I bind a textbox in an MVC view, to a DateTime property in ISO format in my viewmodel, so that it correctly binds the updated value and passes it to my controller method?

## Update

I've replaced my simplified code with most of the actual code. Sorry if it's too much; I can pare it down again if needed.

The context is an imaging system for documents sent to us by our membership. **The field in question is "Submitted"**, a which represents the date we acknowledge receipt of the document. It is the only field which does not make it through binding.

### View Model

```
public class VmDocumentEdit
{
    public enum DocumentAccountEditState
    {
        None,
        ConfirmClear,
        ConfirmSelect,
        Confirmed
    }

    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    #region Account

    public int? AccountId { get; set; }

    public string AccountText { get; set; }

    public VmAccountSearch AccountSearch { get; set; }

    #endregion

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? BatchId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Type")]
    public int DocTypeId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DocTypes { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The date on which the agency received the document, 
    /// regardless of how long it spent in reception/preprocessing.
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? Submitted { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Whether the record is in a valid state to be submitted for review.
    /// </summary>
    public bool ValidForReview { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Whether the record is available for review and release. Check this box
    /// when assignment is done and the document should advance to the review stage.
    /// Uncheck it any time before the review is complete to regress its stage.
    /// </summary>
    public bool SubmittedForReview { get; set; }

    public bool ReturnToBatch { get; set; }

    public VmDocumentPages Pages { get; set; }
}
```

### View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Document", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AccountId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AccountSearch.SelectedAccountId, new { value = -1 })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Submitted)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Pages.SelectedIndex)
    <div id="AccountSearchResultsContainer">

    </div>
    <table class="keyValuePairs fill">
        <tr>
            <th>Account</th>
            <td>
                @if (Model.AccountId.HasValue)
                {
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Account", new { id = Model.AccountId })">@Html.Raw(Model.AccountText)</a>
                }
                else
                {
                    @Model.AccountText
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DocTypeId)</th>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DocTypeId, Model.DocTypes)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DocTypeId)</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Submitted)</th>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Submitted)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Submitted)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="completionContainer">
        <a class="button" href="@Url.Action("Details", "Document", 
                                        new
                                        {
                                                Model.Id, 
                                                Model.Pages.Pagination.StartIndex, 
                                                Model.Pages.SelectedIndex
                                        })">Cancel</a>
        <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
        @if (Model.ValidForReview)
        {
            <label>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.SubmittedForReview) Reviewable</label>
            @: &nbsp;
        }
    </div>
}
```

### Controller Method

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(int? id, int accountId, int docTypeId, DateTime? submitted, int? startIndex, int? selectedIndex)
{
    var document = db.Documents.Where(d => d.Id == id)
            .Include(d => d.Batch)
            .Include(d => d.Account)
            .SingleOrDefault();
    if (document == null) { return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest); }

    // StartIndex is 1-based for user experience; we need a 0-based index
    var vm = GetVmDocumentEdit(document, accountId, startIndex, selectedIndex);
    vm.DocTypeId = docTypeId;
    vm.Submitted = submitted ?? document.Submitted;

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(vm);
    }

    if (document.DocumentStatusKey == DocumentStatusKey.Archive)
    {
        vm.ErrorMessage = "This document is archived and cannot be edited.";

        return View(vm);
    }

    document.DocumentTypeId = docTypeId;
    if (submitted.HasValue) { document.Submitted = submitted.Value; }

    // Account
    if (accountId == -1)
    {
        document.AccountId = null;
        document.SetDocumentStatus(DocumentStatusKey.Processing);
    }
    else
    {
        var account = db.Accounts.Find(accountId);
        if (account == null) { document.AccountId = null; }
        else
        {
            document.AccountId = account.Id;
        }
    }

    var user = ControllerUtility.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
    // Status
    if (document.Account != null && document.DocumentType != null)
    {
        var pendingReview = db.DocumentReviews
                .Where(r => r.DocumentId == document.Id)
                .OrderBy(r=>r.Id)
                .ToList();
        if (pendingReview.Any())
        {
            var last = pendingReview.Last();
            if (last.StatusKey == DocumentReviewStatusKey.Pending)
            {
                db.DocumentReviews.Remove(last);
            }
        }
        db.DocumentReviews.Add(CreateReview(document.Id, user.Id));

        document.SetDocumentStatus(DocumentStatusKey.Review);
    }

    // Review
    // TODO: If review exists cancel it (and handle other end)
    //       Create new review
    //       Update status in Review method

    db.Entry(document).State = EntityState.Modified;
    var documentEvent = new DocumentEvent
    {
        DocumentId = document.Id,
        Keyword = "Edit", 
        Occurred = DateTime.Now,
        UserId = user.Id
    };
    db.DocumentEvents.Add(documentEvent);
    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        vm.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        return View(vm);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = document.Id, startIndex, selectedIndex });
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me and I correctly get a `DateTime` submitted in ISO format in the controller. What is your code in the view?

Comment: Yes, this is a data-binding problem. It doesn't have anything to do with the datetime format. Even if the format was incorrect, you would get *something* posted back if the data is bound properly. We need to see your view. The whole view, or at least the model definition and the code that renders this field *in context* (if there's a foreach loop, for example, included that). If would also help to see the class definition for the model your view is using.

Comment: I've added most of the actual relevant code in the update; it's probably too much, but I thought completeness might better illuminate the problem.

Comment: Do you have a customized editor template for DateTime? The ModelBinder will attempt to parse the date when binding and as long as the form property has the correct name when it's posted and it matches one of the accepted date/time formats that the Date parser accepts.

Comment: I did have an editor template that added the formatting, the placeholder, and a css class. I removed it, but the issue remained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ApplyFormatInEditMode` property is only applied when you use `@Html.EditorFor()`, and is ignored for `@Html.TextBoxFor()` or (in your case) `@Html.HiddenFor()`. Since its not visible, I'm not sure why the format matters (the `DefaultModelBinder` will parse the date correctly if no `DataFormatString` is applied), but you could use

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Submitted, new { @Value = Model.Submitted.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") })
```

to set the value attribute